# Facebook app removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook app has been removed twice from my developer account and my page for non-compliance with facebook guidelines. The first reason invoked was "Give users control over what they share through your app." My voting application shares a message on the timeline of the user for every vote and we have set the right permission for this.
I don't really have any explanation for this situation, especially as I have already launched several applications of this type.

Comment: Platform Policies explicitly say that you should not post messages that the user did not actively create himself.

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me many times already, Facebook is getting more strict with the Privacy Policy compliance.

You can solve this by using the Javascript API to give the user an option to share your content via [Facebook's Share Popup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead of forcing the action.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation and what i did was i changed the way of sharing. Before sharing anything the user was presented with a preview window and in that contents to be shared was shown and the content will get shared only once the user clicks Submit.

This solved the problem.

Thanks